# accessing bytea from json is postgres stored procedure

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a json which has a byte array as value,

```
{
     "backUpdata" : _some binary data_
}
```

I am passing this json to the stored procedure and i am using the below approach to fetch the bytea,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_backup_id(backupJson json) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE  
backupData bytea;  
BEGIN  
backupData := backupJson ->'backUpdata';  
insert into backuprepository values (backupData);  
END  
$$
language plpgsql;
```

My bytea data in json is quite big. If I call this procedure with a json which has so many backupids, the pgadmin select query on configbackuprepository  as below,

```
select * 
from backuprepository;
```

becomes unresponsive.

I want to know if am following right approach in fetching the bytea from json in my stored procedure.

Comment: Stuffing binary data into a `JSONB` doesn't sound like a good idea to me. Why don't you just put it into a `bytea` column? The problem with pgAdmin not being able to display huge amount of data can only be "fixed" by **not** display the complete contents of that table. Just select the row(s) you want to look at.

Comment: There are so many key-value pairs in the json. One of the pair's value  is the bytea. Here in my question, i just mentioned only the bytea for ease.                                                                                                      I am passing the whole json to the stored procedure and fetching the values and stored in respecive columns of the table. One of the value is the bytea.

Comment: As far as I understood, the only issue is regarding pgAdmin not being able to display full scan of your table, which is quite understandable if you have a huge table. If you only want to check the table contents, try to `COPY` to a file and check it yourself using an editor of your preference. pgAdmin, specially the new web version, will certainly cough with a huge amount of data ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes. Pgadmin was not able to bear the huge data as i was using select *. Now i modified the query to select specific columns instead of *.